# Fetching places and directions within a particular place

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

Is it possible to fetch the places/directions within a particular building or place using google maps apis in android or iOS apps? 
For example, can we fetch the shops and its direction inside a shopping mall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [Indoor maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#indoor_maps) of the Google Maps documentation can help you.

At high zoom levels, the map shows floor plans for indoor spaces such as airports, shopping malls, large retail stores, and transit stations. These floor plans, called indoor maps, are displayed for the 'normal' and 'satellite' map types (GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL and GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE). They are automatically enabled when the user zooms in, and they fade away when the map is zoomed out.

For sample code on how to make it, check this [github](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/IndoorDemoActivity.java).

For more information, check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#work_with_indoor_maps_in_the_api) on how to work with indoor maps.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :)